# Unit Tests with Jersey 1.17 Test framework

Tags: jersey, junit4

I want to write unit tests for my Resource classes in my Restful Web application.
I am using jersey version 1.17 and using maven 3.0.2. junit 4.8.1.
*(Just a background, my web application will be deployed on a Jboss server packaged with other components as an ear.)*

Now, I read the Jersey Test framework wiki, but I am unable to find the right set of dependencies to get it working.
There are many versions and artifact and groupIds that are confusing.

Some blogs say

```
<groupId>com.sun.jersey.test.framework</groupId>
```

Whereas others say,

```
<groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
```

while few say, its changed to

```
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
```

I am totally confused.
Please help me figure out the right set dependencies required to write a unit test for Resource Classes. I want to use grizzly container. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Jersey [docs for 1.18](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/chapter_deps.html#d4e1892) say:

> Maven developers require a dependency on the
>   jersey-test-framework-grizzly module. The following dependency needs
>   to be added to the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

which looks like it brings in all the dependencies you'll need. EG `jersey-test-framework-core`